# Can this code be unstable?

Tags: android, rest, authentication

I know this is a weird question and hard to answer without the server code, but maybe somebody spots a irregualrity or has a gues what could be wrong/ not how one normally would do it. 
The issue is: I want to login into our server (our server developer is on vaccation, so I cant ask him for the source code), unfortunately I always get an 400er bad request error "unsupported_bearer_type". Just every like 30th time it works (this is why I ask if it can be unstable). From Swagger and the iOS version of my app I know, that the server dont have any errors, so it must be the android code. 
Therefore my question is, if this code can be somehow unstable or weird?:

```
URL urlToRequest = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlToRequest = new URL(mUrlString);
        urlConnection =
                (HttpURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        String postParameters ="grant_type=password&username=" + email + "&password=" + pw;
        try {
            postParameters = URLEncoder.encode(postParameters, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(
                postParameters.getBytes().length);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        out.print(postParameters);
        out.close();
        int status = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        String line = "";
        String ObjectInString = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            ObjectInString += line;
        }
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(ObjectInString);

        _id = jsonObj.getString("Id");
        String AuthToken = jsonObj.getString("access_token");
        String AuthTokenExpireDate = jsonObj.getString(".expires");
        String RefreshToken = jsonObj.getString("refresh_token");

        ...

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please move this question to the `CodeReview` section

Comment: @KevinWallis Code Review only accepts working code, and since this code doesn't work as intended it is off topic over there.

Comment: @syb0rg okay thanks for the advice